# Monitor Black after Update today 12.04

Tags: 12.04, monitor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Today after installing all available updates, I restarted my PC and my monitor won't display anything. It is strange as I cannot even get it to display a BIOS screen during startup.

The PC is however booting up - the media player is picking up mediaTomb and streaming perfectly well.

I have tried a second monitor, same thing, absolutely no response during any part of boot sequence or thereafter. I have also tried a second cord as well, no difference.

I did recently upgrade monitors and when doing so enabled the nvidia driver rather than using the generic one, but have had no problems until this afternoon.

I am totally aware that this is a question that lacks a lot of details, but I am fairly new to Linux.

As the PC is up and running, I am happy to CTRL-ALT-T a terminal window and type in any suggestions you folks might have to get the monitor displaying anything.

Comment: If your BIOS screen isn't displaying, it's very unlikely that this problem is related to the Ubuntu updates.

Comment: @fluteflute It's the last thing I did. Installed all updates, restarted and black screen. It's the only thing that I can think of. Again though, I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Please see this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/162078/35775

Comment: @Web-E Yeah, I went through that (did a good few hours googling and trying to nut it out. Will duck to the local PC store and try a new card tomorrow. Will update the question with the results from that.

Comment: If you have a external (PCI) graphics card, remove it and try with integrated one.

Comment: @Web-E Excellent suggestion, unfortunately I am using an ASUS P9X79 motherboard (no onboard graphics). I was hoping for a silver bullet/hail mary by posting here.

Comment: @Web-E Thanks for your suggestions. I ended solving the issue and have posted the answer. As strange and baffling as it sounds (I have no idea how this is possible) but it seems that some nvidia drivers came down in the updates which borked the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the latest nvidia drivers that came down in the update somehow threw the system out.

After opening a terminal using CTRL-ALT-T I entered:

```
sudo nvidia-settings --uninstall
```

then typed in my password waited for a half hour (no idea how long the process would take), then restarted the machine. Loaded up perfectly fine.